# CKEditor Code Snippet plugin does not do syntax highlighting in yii2 framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, yii2

I am using CKEditor and its [Code Snippet plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet) in yii2 php framework application. I would like to get syntax highlighting when I write some code using CKEditor, but whatever I do I can not make it work. I have tried everything from the guide like including css and highlight.js in the head but I get nothing... Declaring asset bundle also do not help, yii2 will load files, but highlighting still do not work.

```
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
    'highlight/styles/default.css'
];

public $js = [
    'js/site.js',
    'highlight/highlight.pack.js'
];
```

I am using this widget to install CKEditor in my yii2 site: https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget

Can someone help me out with this ? What do I have to do to make syntax highlighting work ?

EDIT: highlighting is working inside the editor, but I need it for my page where code is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem, I had to include `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` after highlight.pack.js is loaded on my page. There are few ways to do so, I did it like this:

I have included `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` as a part of my site.js script, and I have loaded site.js file **after** the `highlight.pack.js`. So I had to update my Asset bundle like this:

```
public $js = [
    'highlight/highlight.pack.js',
    'js/site.js'
];
```

I had troubles for few hours and didn't realized that solution is that simple. Must be a brain freeze...