# how to enable code snippets in 2amigos ckeditor widget

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can i add code snippets to 2amigos Ckeditor in yii 2

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(),[
'editorOptions' => [
'preset' => 'full',
'inline' => false, 
],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by its creator Antonio Ramirez in [this post answer](http://yiiwheels.com/extension/ckeditor-widget#comment-1911499758):

> The only way to do it and due to the nature of CKEditor where you need
>   to install the plugins you require into its "plugins" directory, The
>   best way would be to extend CKEditorAsset bundle and add the plugin
>   file to be register within its "js" attribute after line 25 [(*Link to
>   line
>   25*)](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/blob/master/src/CKEditorAsset.php#L25)

But I guess he meant after line 23 because the file has changed since then [*(an older commit)*](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/commit/0e09c84b73002e90e63e969d9f1310bae9ebf46e) and because that's how @offline did fixed it in [this StackOverFlow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432332/ckeditor-code-snippet-plugin-does-not-do-syntax-highlighting-in-yii2-framework)